# how rsync_project to run on the remote server

Tags: python, fabric

Here is my scenario:

[image: fabric-question]

I want to execute local fab command to rsync code in the bastion server to the web server parallel, but I find `rsync_project` can only run as a **local** command, fail to find code base path in my local machine.  How to slove this issue, and is there a way to set `local` host string as the bastion server to let rsync_project run on the bastion server properly?

Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to install fabric and rsync_project on 'bastion' and use fabrics "run" to call rsync_project on bastion.

Another option would be to use "get" to receive a copy from bastion and run rsync_project locally. But this approach will not match your picture.